# Python - Can someone explain to me what this does and how it works?

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial to create a text adventure, I'm now creating the sections, still not done, but there's something I just don't understand. So, I'm creating an array for the sections. The array includes description and the name. Now the name of the section has a code that lowers it, replaces spaces with -'s. And it deletes periods and apostrophes. And then puts it in an array called sec. 
This is the part of it which I don't understand:

```
sec = {}
for indexed in enumerate(sections):
    index = indexed[0]
    long_name = indexed[1][1]
    short_name = ''
    for C in long_name:
        if C == ' /':
            short_name += '-'
        elif not C == ".'":
            short_name += C.lower()
    sec[short_name] = index
```

And this is my whole code:

```
    import time
import random
sections = [
    (
        """You are in front of your friend's house. Your friend's house is
(n)orth and the driveway is south. There is a mailbox next to you.""",
        "Front Of Friend's House"), #0
    (
        """You are in your friend's house. Northwest is the stairs, the
kitchen is up north, the door is south. Your friend is upstairs.""",
        "Friend's house"), #1
    (
        """You are upstairs, the bathroom is up north, your friend's bedroom
is west. The stair down is south.""",
        "Friend's house upstairs"), #2
    ]

sec = {}
for indexed in enumerate(sections):
    index = indexed[0]
    long_name = indexed[1][1]
    short_name = ''
    for C in long_name:
        if C == ' /':
            short_name += '-'
        elif not C == ".'":
            short_name += C.lower()
    sec[short_name] = index
```

Can somebody explain the part to me of which I don't understand, I don't like writing something without knowing what I'm doing. I also don't know what *for* means. And how C can be used without it being defined or something. If you could explain this to me that would be great!

Comment: I assume you've [looked it up in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)? Which part of it is unclear?

Comment: `for` is a loop. The body is executed multiple times, once for each element of `long_name`. On each execution of the body, the variable `C` is set equal to the current element. However, the code is incorrect. `long_name` is a string, its elements are 1 character long, so will never be equal to `' /'` or to `".'"` which are both 2 characters long. It's possible you meant to write `if C in ' /':` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the code slightly clearer, in the enumerate section. `enumerate` allows iteration over pairs of `iteration number, iteration item`, so you might as well assign the variables separately.  I suggest experimenting with straightforward iteration (`for directionpair in sections:`) and enumeration (`for index,directionpair in enumerate(sections)`) to see the difference.

From reading your description, you should be using the keyword `in` to check whether C is in the string "'." or "\ ", as no character could ever be equal to a two-character string.

```
sec = {} #construct a dictionary
for index, directionpair in enumerate(sections):
    long_name = directionpair[1] #take the second element of the pair
    short_name = ''
    for C in long_name: #for each character in long_name
        if C in ' /': #every time you find a forward slash in long_name, write '-' in short-name instead
            short_name += '-'
        elif C not in "'." : #in short-string, add all lower-case versions of the character if it's not a '.'
            short_name += C.lower()
    sec[short_name] = index
```

Note that this could have been done more easily with the correct functions, and actually even the expression below could be improved with `re.sub`:

```
sec = {} #construct a dictionary
for index, directionpair in enumerate(sections):
    long_name = directionpair[1] #take the second element of the pair
    short_name = long_name.replace('/','-').replace(' ','-').replace("'",'').replace('.','').lower()
    sec[short_name] = index
```

Comment: You could also do `for index, (_, long_name) in enumerate(sections):`. `_` (perhaps surprisingly) is a valid Python variable name, traditionally used when you're ignoring part of an unpacked tuple. In this case, the first value in each section is unused.

Comment: Very true...you could even do it as a one-line function, e.g. `sec={ln.replace('/','-').replace('.','').lower():ind for(ind,(_,ln)) in enumerate(sections)}`

Comment: What does long_name = directionpair[1] do? And for index, directionpair?

Comment: You are iterating over sections, which is a list of pairs.  The iteration assigns `directionpair` to each pair from `sections` in turn. `directionpair[0]` is the first element of the pair; `directionpair[1]` is the second element of the pair.

Comment: If you want a better understanding of what iterators do, you can step through them like this: assign your iterator to a variable, e.g. `iter=enumerate(sections)`.  Then use `iter.next()` to see each output of the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer which will become clear after you read the documentation of `for` statements in Python.

1. `indexed` iterates through the elements of `sections` which are numbered from 0.  E.g., in the first iteration, `indexed` is `(0, ("""You are in front...""", "Front..."))`
2. `long_name` is the second element of the section, i.e., `"Front..."`.
3. `C` iterates through the characters of the long name which is converted to lowercase.  There must be something wrong there, in the two comparisons of `C` against strings that are longer than a character.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a string breaks it up into characters in Python. So

```
for C in 'foo':
    print C
```

will print

```
f
o
o
```